# Is it possible to define a object which holds and manipulates its own values?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Somthing in this direction? Here jobs is undefined in the functions addJob and runNext is there the possibility to get this work?

```
const myThing = {
    jobs: [],
    addJob: (id, job) => {
        jobs.push({id: id, job: job})
    },
    runNext: () => {
        jobs.shift().job()
    }
}
```

Comment: this kind pf problem has a name hasnt it? Something with visibility? Does someone know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a factory-function or a class to achieve this:

**Factory Function:**

```js
function myThing() {
  const jobs = [];

  return {
    addJob: (id, job) => {
      jobs.push({
        id: id,
        job: job
      })
    },
    runNext: () => {
      jobs.shift().job()
    },
    print: () => {
      console.log(jobs);
    }
  };

}

const instance = myThing();

instance.addJob("someId", "someJob")
instance.print();
```

**Class:**

```js
class MyThing {
  jobs = [];


  addJob(id, job) {
    this.jobs.push({
      id: id,
      job: job
    });
  }

  runNext() {
    this.jobs.shift().job()
  }

  print() {
    console.log(this.jobs);
  }
}

const instance = new MyThing();

instance.addJob("someId", "someJob");
instance.print();
```